# Load DIV contents to CKEditor textarea (keep formatting)

Tags: javascript, jquery, format, ckeditor, clipboard

I have CKEditor on my forum page. Forum items are DIVs, including formatting (strong, h1-6 etc). I want to make a small button at each post, which copies contents of that DIV to CKEditor textarea - so everyone can copy some previous post, update it and save as new post.
My forum works with bbCode, so I am using bbCode plugin for CKEditor. However, whenever I load data using jQuery

```
var post = $("DIV_post_selector").html();
```

and paste it to CKEditor like

```
CKEDITOR.instances.addPost.setData(post);
```

the html code is added into texteditor, which is obviously wrong. However, when I copy/paste it standardly, text is added correctly (without HTML tags, yet keeping format). Any possibility to do it programatically, without clipboard raping?

Comment: Request the post's original BBcode from the server / database and insert that into the editor.

Comment: Same result, only that shown is bbcode source instead of html source

Comment: Nah, im an idiot. Ive been testing your solution with invalid bbcode. Your solution works like charm. Thanks for pointing my frozen brain to correct direction

Comment: Cool, you're welcome!